# I want to start a new activity from this activity.But it didnt show up after showing "success". I don't know what's the problem in this code

Tags: android, android-activity, registration

```
    private void register(final String name, final String city, final String bloodgroup, final String password, final String mobileno)
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest =  new 
        StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Endpoints.register_url,new
        Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
               if (response.equals("Success")){
                   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   startActivity (new Intent (RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                   finish ();
               }else{
                   Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Something went wrong :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("VOLLEY",error.getMessage());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
               params.put("name", name);
                params.put("city", city);
                params.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
                params.put("password", password);
                params.put("number", mobileno);
               return params;
            }
        };
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

I want to start a new activity from this activity.But it didnt show up after showing "success". I don't know what's the problem in this code.

Comment: something in logs?

Comment: no errors while debugging.but not shown up another activity

Answer (score 0):

try remove `finish () ;`

I hope it will work with you.